# SonarQube: Remove the extra characters before the open tag

Tags: php, html, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have this code in my file index.phtml. This code is a part of a page:

```
<br/><br/>
<div id="view-content">
    <p>
        blablablablablablablabla
        <strong>
            blabla
        </strong>
        blabla
        <strong>
            blabla
        </strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

I use SonarQube and it displays this bug:

> Remove the extra characters before the open tag

I don't understand this error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for blank lines before PHP opening or closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336082/checking-for-blank-lines-before-php-opening-or-closing-tag)

Comment: It's not the same problem. This code is a part of a page

Comment: Are you sure that there is no BOM character at the beginning of the file? You will not see it in a standard editor as it is a non-printable character

Comment: I use the IDE PhpStorm: Global Encoding UTF-8

Comment: Then use the "File | Remove BOM" action of the phpstorm ide menu and make sure there is no other characters before the <?php opening tag

Comment: How can I do that ? I don't have <?php in the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194604/discussion-between-fatma-wings-and-jeprubio).

Comment: Sorry, this solution is not working :(

Comment: I solved my problem. I use <?php //comments ?> in the beggin of the page

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I use `<?php //comments ?>` in the begin of the page.